# Error while trying to save a smart object with a transparency mask

Tags: layers, mask, creative-cloud, smartobject

I embedded a jpg in my main picture and edit it (smart object). I edit the sky and need transparency background. But when I try save the smart object I got error. See the Screenshot. I read in an article about 1 year ago, that was a bug in cs6?

[image]

Comment: JPGs can't contain transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this makes sense. Jpg's can not have clipping masks (you can embed vector paths). You need to save this as a PSD, and then just use the File>Place command when in your original document. OR just drag the "Layer 0" into the original file "Godzilla".